# Placing two divs side by side and one to stretch to take up the space

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to accomplish layout below with divs. My current code doesn't work well. How can I do It?

Thanks

Current code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uz9NF/2/)

[image]

Actual items in my code are :

```
#body_block
{
    background-color: #B8B8B8;
}
#body
{
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
}
#body_left
{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: #FFE0F8;
}
#body_right
{
    background-color: #E1FFE0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
I've wrapped both divs with `<section>`

Thanks

```
/*** BODY-MYACCOUNT *************************/
section { display: table; width: 100%;}
section div { display: table-cell; border: 1px solid #000; }
#body_left
{
    background-color: #FFE0F8;margin-right: 50px;
}
#body_right
{
    background-color: #E1FFE0;width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It's actually using the "display: table" that's made it work rather than the section wrapper. You could have also used that on your div.

Answer (score 0):

on you

```
#body_right
{  
    float:left;
    background-color: #E1FFE0;
}
```

you also need to add the **float left** setting, then on your footer_block you need to then add a **clear: both**;

```
   #footer_block
  {
       clear:both;
   background-color: #B3B3B3;
 }
```

should help you start

Comment: 1. Background of body block is gone white. 2. `#body_right` won't stretch to fit in the space on the right.

Comment: add a height: 100%; to the body_block should work as tested locally if you look @BFDatabaseAdmin it ssome wwhat better as here reconstructed your code and thats what i would have done but not enough time

Answer (score 0):

1,use absolute like this http://jsfiddle.net/yujiangshui/uz9NF/7/

2,use jquery , when $(window).load() give low height div the other div's height

3,use the follow code:

```
<div class="out">
  <div class="div1">
    div1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    div2
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.out{overflow:hidden; width:650px; margin:0 auto;}
.div1{padding-bottom: 5000px; margin-bottom: -5000px; width:490px; background:#ff1; float:left; margin-right:10px;height:400px;}
.div2{padding-bottom: 5000px; margin-bottom: -5000px; width:150px; background:#ccc; float:left;height:800px;}
```

4,use `<table>`

Althought my English is poor, but hope my answer can give you some help!

Answer (score 0):

you also add the position property of the css

I mean position: relative; to the outer division inside which the two left and right divisions are present.

then use the same float: left and float: right to the left and right container respectively.

I think this will work.